# Why does my database migration fail after creating an association between users and posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm creating a writing app where a user has_many posts.

I generated a migration to add the user id to posts, and I'm now receiving this error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "user_id" integer/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Here's the migration where I added user_id to posts:

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

I've run two previous migrations, one to create the posts and one to create users using Devise. Those two files are below.

Here's the migration for creating users with Devise:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

And here's the migration for creating posts:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body1
      t.text :body2
      t.text :body3

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I understand the logic behind the error, but I don't see where or how to fix it.

Do I have to alter these files, destroy the migrations and run them again, or do something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from `add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer` to `add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer, index: true`

Comment: Hm, now a new error: StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "user_id"

Comment: When I run my application on the local server, it gives me an error that says migrations are pending and tells me to run bin/rake db:migrate ENV=development

Comment: it means that you already have the column user_id. drop the column, delete the file, then run a new migration as stated before `add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer, index: true`

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by drop the column? Do I run a command on the command line, or change something in a file? Sorry, very much a novice when it comes to interacting with databases. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try running the `add_index` after your first `end` in the `AddUserIdToPosts` migration. You may need to `$ rake db:rollback` first.

Comment: Do you mean moving the line add_index :posts, :user_id in that file so that it comes after the first end? And then running rake db:migrate? If so, that did not work.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: You need to run rake db:rollback first

Comment: I ran rake db:rollback, then moved the add_index line so, it comes after the first "end," then ran rake db:migrate. I still receive an error: ArgumentError: Index name 'index_posts_on_user_id' on table 'posts' already exists